# Joining tables with identical (non-keyed) column names in R data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

How do you deal with identically named, non-key columns when joining data.tables? I am looking for a solution to `table.field` notation in SQL.

For instance, lets' say I have a table DT that is repopulated with new data for column `v`  every time period. I also have a table DT_HIST that stores entries from previous time periods (`t`). I want to find the difference between the current and previous time period for each `x`

In this case: DT is time period 3, and DT_HIST has time periods 1 and 2:

```
 DT <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4),v=c(20,20,35,30))
 setkey(DT,x)
 DT_HIST <- data.table(x=rep(seq(1,4,1),2),v=c(40,40,40,40,30,25,45,40),t=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)))
 setkey(DT_HIST,x)

> DT
   x  v
1: 1 20
2: 2 20
3: 3 35
4: 4 30

> DT_HIST
   x  v t
1: 1 40 1
2: 1 30 2
3: 2 40 1
4: 2 25 2
5: 3 40 1
6: 3 45 2
7: 4 40 1
8: 4 40 2
```

I would like to join `DT` with `DT_HIST[t==1,]` on `x` and calculate the difference in `v`.

Just joining the tables results in columns `v` and `v.1`.

```
> DT[DT_HIST[t==2],]
   x  v v.1 t
1: 1 20  30 2
2: 2 20  25 2
3: 3 35  45 2
4: 4 30  40 2
```

However, I can't find a way to refer to the different `v` columns when doing the join.

```
> DT[DT_HIST[t==2],list(delta=v-v.1)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, DT_HIST[t == 2], list(delta = v - v.1)) : 
object 'v.1' not found

> DT[DT_HIST[t==2],list(delta=v-v)]
   x delta
1: 1     0
2: 2     0
3: 3     0
4: 4     0
```

If this is a duplicate, I apologize. I searched and couldn't find a similar question.

Also, I realize that I can simply rename the columns after joining and then run my desired expression, but I want to know if I'm doing this in the completely wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `i.colname` to access the column in the `i`-expression `data.table`. I see you're using an old `data.table` version. There have been a few changes since then: the duplicated joined column names have a prefix `i.` instead of a number postfix (making it more consistent with the `i.` access of joined column names, and there is no by-without-by anymore by default.

In the latest version (1.9.3), this is what you get:

```
DT[DT_HIST[t==2],list(delta = v - i.v)]
#   delta
#1:   -10
#2:    -5
#3:   -10
#4:   -10
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a newb question, but why are there newer stable versions that aren't on CRAN?

Comment: @Z.Kimble that's just the workflow of `data.table` - odd versions are development versions and even ones are more stable and go to CRAN