# In R, avoiding when merging two data tables with same column names duplicated unkeyed cols?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Please help a beginner improve their understanding of the amazing data.table package on an basic problem.

I want to **update a data table** `dt` with new snippets of information with the **same structure and column names** `dt2`, ticker / date / price. Key is ticker and date.

1. I know one could use `rbind(dt, dt2)` [looking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940805/joining-tables-with-identical-non-keyed-column-names-in-r-data-table) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940805/joining-tables-with-identical-non-keyed-column-names-in-r-data-table), but I don't want to risk duplicates, so thought rather join them through a merge.
2. I was expecting **`merge(dt, dt2, all = TRUE)`** to do the trick.

   But you get *x.price y.price* and not a single *price* column!?

   Why does `dt` not match the shared columns in 2?  Data frame docs imply they use intersect of names but DT seems different.
3. Currently, I am getting around it with  **`by = colnames(dt)`** i.e. `merge(dt, dt2, all = TRUE,  by = colnames(dt))`, **but is this the right way to do it**?

Thanks I would appreciate some guidance/confirmation (and without resorting to another package).

**Example Code**

```
library(data.table)
# Main data
dt <- data.table(ticker = c("A", "A"), 
                 date   = c("Jan", "Feb"),
                 price  = c(10, 11),
                 key    = c("ticker", "date"))

# Update data with same column names
dt2 <- data.table(ticker = c("A", "B"), 
                  date   = c("Mar", "Mar"),
                  price  = c(12, 100),
                  key    = c("ticker", "date"))

# Lets put them together
merge(dt, dt2, all = TRUE)
# but get 4 x 4 back (not 4 x 3) with price.x price.y ???

    ticker date price.x price.y
1:      A  Feb      11      NA
2:      A  Jan      10      NA
3:      A  Mar      NA      12
4:      B  Mar      NA     100

# This works, but am I missing easier syntax?
merge(dt, dt2, all = TRUE, by = colnames(dt2))

   ticker date price
1:      A  Feb    11
2:      A  Jan    10
3:      A  Mar    12
4:      B  Mar   100
```

(An aside) Is it better practice in R to be clear and specify `merge.data.table`?

Comment: Have a look at `?merge.data.table`. The `by` defaults to the common key columns and this is why specifying `by=colnames(dt2)` gives a different result than omitting the `by` argument (which then defaults to the first two columns).

Comment: That's because you've set `key  = c("ticker", "date")` in `dt`. Change it to `key    = c("ticker", "date", "price")`. And you don't need to specify the key in `dt2` at all. Re your second question. `merge` is a generic function so it doesn't care if you write `merge` or `merge.data.table`. But if you want to escape the method dispatch overhead, `merge.data.table` could be a bit faster. This is all appears in documentation of `?merge`

Comment: Thanks @konvas and David. I need the key later in the code. So that's why I am looking for a temporary override for unkeyed columns. Do you guys  suggest I just go with this colnames thing, or do you unkey and reset keys often with DT?